# offensive getter, defensive setter

Tags: java, getter-setter

I am currently learning java and found something I could not find an answer to in the instructions for my homework.

The instruction describes getter and setter methods as follows:

> - getPic: returns the pic (offensive getter)
> - setPic: creates a copy of the given pic (defensive setter)

I could not find an answer to what **offensive getter** and **defensive setter** mean.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Many thanks!

Comment: The instructions contain what you need to do. `setPic: creates a copy of the given pic` - creating a copy makes the setter defensive. `getPic: returns the pic` - returning the pic (instead of a copy of the pic) makes the getter offensive.

Comment: It means you must protect (defense) your class (add validation) to your setters, and just return your field in your getters.

Comment: BTW what is your source?

Comment: No, *defensive* does not mean that.

Comment: Accordingly, you can also make your getter defensive by returning a copy of the pic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen this terminology before, and I think it's not used much. But based on your question I think it probably means the following:

**Defensive getter**: that which returns a copy of an internal object, instead of the object itself, so that external code can alter the returned object without affecting the internal state of the class:

```
Foo getFoo() {
    return this.foo.clone();
}
```

**Offensive getter**: that which is not defensive

```
Foo getFoo() {
    return this.foo;
}
```

**Defensive setter**: same story. Create a copy of the object so that external changes to the original object don't affect internal state.

```
void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo.clone();
}
```

**Offensive setter**: not defensive

```
void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

Comment: And the distinction is void/meaningless if the value is immutable.

Comment: thank you for this detailed explanation! I already started to doubt my ability to google ;)

Answer (score 3):

My *guess* is as follows: 
The term defensive means that the internal object is protected. So a defensive getter would not return the image but a copy or immutable facade.
In turn an offensive setter would simply overwrite the image. 
But again, this is a best guess. I never heard the terms before.

Comment: I agree, those are not common names, I suppose your teacher wanted to sound smart. I would guess the same way as Christoph.

Comment: *"offensive setter would simply overwrite the image"*. If that is the distinction, what does a defensive setter do, if it cannot update the image? --- My *guess* would rather be, that the difference is whether it copies the image, i.e. whether it is susceptible to changes to the image made by the caller after the setter returns.

Comment: Yes, a defensive setter could do just that. That way the internal object would be decoupled from the outside again. I never did that, though. Defensive getters, yes. Especially with Collections.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I never heard of this terminology before. Quick Google check shows that it's not the "usual" terminology either.

*Defensive* probably comes from [Make defensive copies when needed](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2), Item 24 from Effective Java. Basically you'll make (by whatever means) a copy of the *pic* which is passed to your setter. Since you've made a copy of the *pic*, the "attacker" can no longe change the *pic* you have in your instance by modifying the *pic* which was passed to the setter.

*Offensive* then must mean that you don't defend (ex. in the getter), you just return the value directly. You could have also been defensive here, returning a copy of *pic* once again.

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with what *encapsulation* means for a language like Java. In an object-oriented language our objects typically have an internal state.

```
class Picture {
   Image picture;

   public void Picture(Image img) {
       this.picture = img;
   }
}
```

here we have a simple class that contains an image called picture and the constructor adds the image to it.

Now let's say we want access to it after it's been instantiated. We could simple have a method like:

```
public Image getImg() {
   return this.picture;
}
```

But we're handing out our actual image, this would be an offensive getter. We are handing out reference to our internal state letting someone else reach inside of us and change something.

A defensive getter would prevent altering the internal state of the object by first making a copy, possibly using `.clone`.

```
public Image getImg() {
   Image copy = this.picture.clone();
   return copy;
}
```